# Add new interface and prop to imported component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import TextField and add inputMode prop from NumberField component. So I added inputMode in the `interface` and also used `...rest` in the TextField in order to receive new props. But currently I'm getting this error:

Type '{ inputMode: "numeric"; onChange: (value: string) => void; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextFieldProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'inputMode' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextFieldProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Just trying to add one more prop. Any advice would be appreciated. Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/numberfield-component-ts-wohlok?file=/src/NumberField.tsx:0-686

TextField.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export interface ITextFieldProps {
  type?: "text" | "search";
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const TextField: React.FunctionComponent<ITextFieldProps> = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  ITextFieldProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const { type = "text", onChange, required = true, ...rest } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
    onChange?.(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required={required}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
});
```

NumberField.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ITextFieldProps, TextField } from "./TextField";

export interface INumberFieldProps extends ITextFieldProps {
  inputMode?: "numeric";
}

export const NumberField: React.FunctionComponent<INumberFieldProps> = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  INumberFieldProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const { inputMode = "numeric", onChange } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(value: string) {
    const updatedValue = value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    setValue(updatedValue);
    onChange?.(updatedValue);
  }

  return (
    <TextField inputMode={inputMode} onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## New answer

If you want an `<input>` with type `text` and inputMode `numeric`, do it like so. I also recommend you update your TextField:

```
import { HTMLAttributes, forwardRef } from 'react';

export interface ITextFieldProps {
  type?: 'text' | 'search';
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  required?: boolean;
  inputMode?: HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>['inputMode'];
  value?: string;
}

export const TextField: React.FunctionComponent<ITextFieldProps> = forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  ITextFieldProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const { type = 'text', onChange, required = true, inputMode, value } = props;

  function handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    onChange?.(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required={required}
      inputMode={inputMode}
    />
  );
});

TextField.displayName = 'TextField';
```

No change needed in `NumberField`.

## Old answer

Your HTML should conform to standards. `inputMode="numeric"` is not the right way to make a numeric input. The right way is `type="number"`.

```
export interface ITextFieldProps {
  type?: "text" | "search" | "number"; // <--- Add "number" here
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  required?: boolean;
}
```

Then in your `NumberField.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ITextFieldProps, TextField } from "./TextField";

export interface INumberFieldProps extends ITextFieldProps {
  type?: "number"; // <--- Rename prop
  onChange?: () => void;
}

export const NumberField: React.FunctionComponent<INumberFieldProps> = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  INumberFieldProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const { type = "number", onChange } = props; // <--- Rename prop
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(value: string) {
    const updatedValue = value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    setValue(updatedValue);
    onChange?.(updatedValue);
  }

  return (
    <TextField type={type} onChange={handleChange} value={value} /> // <--- Rename prop
  );
});
```

This should work, but to further improve the code, you can omit the `type` in `INumberFieldProps` altogether, because its value can only ever be `number`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ITextFieldProps, TextField } from "./TextField";

export interface INumberFieldProps extends ITextFieldProps {
  onChange?: () => void; // <--- Remove `type`
}

export const NumberField: React.FunctionComponent<INumberFieldProps> = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  INumberFieldProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const { onChange } = props; // <--- Remove `type`
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(value: string) {
    const updatedValue = value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    setValue(updatedValue);
    onChange?.(updatedValue);
  }

  return (
    <TextField type="number" onChange={handleChange} value={value} /> // <--- Hard-code `type="number"`
  );
});
```

Comment: Actually I need type="text" since type="number" has numerous browser and accessibility issues. I would like to keep it string so something like "232". I have question regarding renaming prop from INumberFieldProps. Is changing prop value allowed when interface is extending one another? I thought I could only add more props.

Comment: @JudoboyAlex ah okay, in that case I will update my answer. Regarding your question, yes you can narrow prop value. If `ITextFieldProps` accept `type?: "text" | "search" | "number";`, `INumberFieldProps` which extends it can accept a subset: `type?: "number"`. Narrowing possible values is possible, as long as you don't use a whole new value such as `type?: "password"`

Answer (score -1):

`inputMode` is not contained in the `ITextFieldProps` interface, so you won't be able to access the property or assign a value to it.

Try adding `[key: string]: any;` to the `ITextFieldProps` interface if you don't know explicitly the type that you'll send as a prop like so:

```
export interface ITextFieldProps {
  type?: "text" | "search";
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  required?: boolean;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Then it should work.

Forked Sandbox: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/numberfield-component-ts-forked-bv7oed)

Comment: I think `any` isn't a good practice in TypeScript, and this line doesn't make your code safer